# Issue with Bootstrap modal on Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-modal, ng-bootstrap

I'm working on an angular2 project, and We use the package "bootstrap": "~3.3.7".

We are having an issue when trying to open the modal. When we inspect the HTML it shows the following

```
<ngb-modal-backdrop class="modal-backdrop fade show"></ngb-modal-backdrop>
<ngb-modal-window role="dialog" style="display: block;" tabindex="-1" ng-reflect-class-name="modal fade show" class="modal fade show">
```

Notice that the in the class property, there is a class 'Show' for the backdrop and for the window. But if we change this manually on the developers console and switch the 'show' for an 'in', the modals appears on screen.

We are not doing anything weird when calling the modal:

```
this.modalDialog = this.modalService.open(SiteSettingsEditDialog);
```

Any idea what could be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home) works only with Bootstrap 4 CSS so you will have to update your Bootstrap package to 4.0.0-alpha.6.

[ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home) project took decision to support Bootstrap 4 only since Bootstrap 3 is not maintained any more by the Bootstrap team and all the development happens on version 4 only.

Comment: Yeah changing it to the 4 version brings the popup but it mess all other styles already in the project. I guess we will have to look for another modal popup in angular2